# Iframe not run a html file

Tags: html, file, iframe, call

Can anyone help?

I want to create an iframe that runs the html script that is inside a html file on another site.

In the html file exists an html code for a search bar. I want my current site run the file and display the search bar.

Below is an example of code, but it does not run the html script. He tries to download the file.

Example code:

```
<iframe src = "https://sites.google.com/mycolors/colors.html> </ iframe>
```

Comment: given that the url doesn't work at all, why would you expect anything to actually happen?

Comment: In the html file exists an html code for a search bar. I want my current site run the file and display the search bar.

Comment: that's fine, but your url above comes up as "site does not exist".

Comment: I typed the url (the first one) in my browser (Firefox), the url works but it tries to make me download a file. The issue comes from the url you are trying to include in the first place.

Comment: this has NOTHING to do with your iframe. go to that url with your browser, you get prompted for a download.

Comment: Looking at the updated URL: **read the error messages in your developer tools console**. They tell you why it doesn't display.